# Scanner doesn't work anymore after upgrading to Linux Mint 18

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, scanning, epson

After having migrated from Linux Mint 17.3 to Linux Mint 18.1, my scanner doesn't work anymore. My scanner is Epson Stylus SX445W.

Before when executing the command `scanimage -L`, I was able to see only one scanner. Now I have two whereas only one scanner is connected to the computer:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epson2:libusb:002:008' is a Epson PID 0884 flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:usb:002:008' is a Epson Stylus TX435W/NX430/SX440W 
Series flatbed scanner
```

Does anyone have this problem and how to get hints to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I post it here if it can help someone.

With versions prior to Linux Mint 18, the Epson driver was necessary to make the scanner work but it's not the case anymore (supported out of the box).

For this, we need to remove the deb package for this driver: packages isane*.

After having removed them, execute the following command:

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0884) at libusb:002:010
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

After that, I can see my scanner in the list with the command `scanimage -L`:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `epson2:libusb:002:010' is a Epson PID 0884 flatbed scanner
```

We can then use again the scanner using XSane!